# TypeError: map.addMarker is not a function

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework

I can't call any function by map object.

The map works correctly but I need to add marker or call any function, I couldn't do that.

Is my problem with code or with plugins?

```
   // create location object
   const location = new google.maps.LatLng('24.713552', '46.675296');

   // create options object
   const options = {
       center:location, 
       zoom: 10,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
       draggable: true 
     };

   // create location object
   const map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapRef.nativeElement, options);

    map.off();// this for e.g.
   map.addMarker(markerOptions ).then(marker => {
    //alert(marker);
  });// or this
```

Please check plugins in package.json

```
"@angular/animations": "^5.2.11",
"@angular/common": "^5.2.11",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.2.11",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.11",
"@angular/core": "^5.2.11",
"@angular/forms": "^5.2.11",
"@angular/http": "^5.2.11",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.11",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.11",
"@angular/router": "^5.2.11",
"@ionic-native/core": "^4.9.1",
"@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.11.0",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.7.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.7.0",
"@ionic/pro": "1.0.20",
"@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
"com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": "~1.1.18",
"cordova": "^8.0.0",
"cordova-android": "^7.0.0",
"cordova-common": "^2.2.5",
"cordova-plugin-device": "~2.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-device-motion": "^2.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk": "git+https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk.git#2.7.0",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.2.1",
"cordova-plugin-shake": "^0.6.0",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "~5.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "~1.3.3",
"cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "~5.4.1",
"cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.3.3",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"minimist": "^1.2.0",
"moment": "^2.22.2",
"ng-lazyload-image": "^3.4.2",
"platform": "1.3.5",
"rxjs": "^5.5.11",
"sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
"uuid": "^3.2.1",
"xml2js": "^0.4.19",
"zone.js": "0.8.26"


  "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
  "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
  "cordova-plugin-device": {},
  "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
  "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
  "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
  "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": {},
  "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
  "cordova-plugin-device-motion": {},
  "cordova-plugin-shake": {},
  "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": {
    "API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": "AIzaSyC4d2sLV_TD274bRUqNqBtGtDVUZFURM3k",
    "API_KEY_FOR_IOS": "AIzaSyC4d2sLV_TD274bRUqNqBtGtDVUZFURM3k",
    "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "11.8.0",
    "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "24.1.0"
  },
  "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {}
```

The keys only for developing not for production, I test app with browser.

Comment: can you share your full ts file (component's code). Most likely you have a pointer issue within execution scopes somewhere

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqfaliB5cNSKibJx4ZjASea_fgKAug

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqfaliB5cNSKibJyMKl_9Gs8ACySbQ

Comment: let me know if my answer helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. To create Google Map there are two ways:

1- JavaScript side, like:

```
   // create location object
   const location = new google.maps.LatLng('24.713552', '46.675296');

   // create options object
   const options = {
       center:location, 
       zoom: 10,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
       draggable: true 
     };

   // create location object
   const map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapRef.nativeElement, options);
```

2- native side, like:

```
this.map = GoogleMaps.create('address-map', mapOptions);
```

My main problem when I try to mix between them, so I could not call addmarker with JavaScript side.

Full solution is:

```
   // create location object
   const location = new google.maps.LatLng('24.713552', '46.675296');

   // create options object
   const options = {
       center:location, 
       zoom: 10,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
       draggable: true 
     };

   // create location object
   const map = new google.maps.Map(mapRef, options);

   // call add marker
   this.marker = this.AddMarker(location, map);

   // call add listener
   google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'dragend', () => {
        // toggle bounce
        this.toggleBounce(this.marker);
   });

   // call add listener
   google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'click', () => {
   // alert(this.marker);
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like during you page component load lifecycle method (ionViewDidLoad) you call DisplayMap method which has 'this' reference inside that starts to point to its own scope as opposed to your component's scope. Try changing that method with fat arrow function assignment. This way DisplayMap method won't create its own 'this' pointer:

See below:

```
import { NavController, Platform, AlertController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';   
import { AddressService } from '../../Providers/address.service';
import { ApiDomain } from '../../Providers/constant';
import { CartPage } from '../cart/cart';  
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

declare var google: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-chooselocation',
  templateUrl: 'chooselocation.html'
})

export class ChooseLocationPage {

  rootUrl: String = "";   


  animationsOptions = {
    animation: 'ios-transition',
    duration: 1000
  }

  @ViewChild('map') mapRef : ElementRef; 

  // constructor
  constructor( public platform: Platform,
              public storage: Storage,
              public alertCtrl: AlertController,
              public toastCtrl: ToastController,
              public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public translate: TranslateService, 
              public service: AddressService) {

      // read root URL
      this.rootUrl = ApiDomain.rootUrl;

  } 

  // ion view did load
  ionViewDidLoad()
  {    
      // display map
      this.DisplayMap(); 
  }


  // display map
  DisplayMap = () => {    
       // read current location

       // create location object
       const location = new google.maps.LatLng('24.713552', '46.675296');

       // create options object
       const options = {
           center:location, 
           zoom: 10,
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
           draggable: true 
         };

       // create location object
       const map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapRef.nativeElement, options);

       const markerOptions = {
         position: location, 
         animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
       };


       map.addMarker(markerOptions ).then(marker => {
             alert(marker);
       });



  } 

}
```

Alternatively you can try passing your native element reference to DisplayMap method as an argument, but I am unsure if this.mapRef.nativeElement reference is "ready" during ionViewDidLoad method, so its better to check if its valid.

```
import { NavController, Platform, AlertController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';   
import { AddressService } from '../../Providers/address.service';
import { ApiDomain } from '../../Providers/constant';
import { CartPage } from '../cart/cart';  
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

declare var google: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-chooselocation',
  templateUrl: 'chooselocation.html'
})

export class ChooseLocationPage {

  rootUrl: String = "";   


  animationsOptions = {
    animation: 'ios-transition',
    duration: 1000
  }

  @ViewChild('map') mapRef : ElementRef; 

  // constructor
  constructor( public platform: Platform,
              public storage: Storage,
              public alertCtrl: AlertController,
              public toastCtrl: ToastController,
              public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public translate: TranslateService, 
              public service: AddressService) {

      // read root URL
      this.rootUrl = ApiDomain.rootUrl;

  } 

  // ion view did load
  ionViewDidLoad()
  {    
      // display map
      this.DisplayMap(this.mapRef.nativeElement); 
  }


  // display map
  DisplayMap(mapRef) {    
       // read current location

       // create location object
       const location = new google.maps.LatLng('24.713552', '46.675296');

       // create options object
       const options = {
           center:location, 
           zoom: 10,
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
           draggable: true 
         };

       // create location object
       const map = new google.maps.Map(mapRef, options);

       const markerOptions = {
         position: location, 
         animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
       };


       map.addMarker(markerOptions ).then(marker => {
             alert(marker);
       });



  } 

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the error still appear :(
please any other solution??

Comment: yes, same!
but when i change 
 // create location object
       const map = new google.maps.Map(mapRef, options);
to
this.map = GoogleMaps.create('address-map', mapOptions);  
error has hidden, but i'm getting blank page...
should test on real device?? or can i do that with browser??

Comment: So which solution you tried? fat arrow? can you console.log(map) after it gets initialized? (before addMarker is called) Can you please update your question with the latest code implementation you have. What you mentioned in your comment is not what was there;/

Comment: I tried ur solution no change at all !!!
with solution in my previous comment I got blank page with no error

Comment: after console.log(map); i got : Native: tried accessing the GoogleMaps plugin but Cordova is not available. Make sure to a) run in a real device or simulator and b) include cordova.js in your index.html

Comment: so are you trying these changes on a real device or not? second question - where is native plugin gets imported? the code you shared has no such import? which service provider has it - can you list your full code context?

Comment: on real device no error, but only google logo appears

Comment: can you upload all of your code over to stackblitz.com? or make it available in other way. Its hard to help you just seeing part of the code;/ I mentioned above that I wanted to see how and which plugins you are importing

Comment: also did you try following this guide: https://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-2-how-to-use-google-maps-geolocation-video-tutorial/